# PHP INSERT INTO localhost not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

After running a SELECT * FROM users, there is no difference to the table.

```
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $dateOfBirth = $_POST["dateOfBirth"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    $fitnessLevel = $_POST["fitnessLevel"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    $db = 'gymmembers';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die("Error, try again");


    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(`firstName`,`lastName`,`dateOfBirth`,`gender`,`fitnessLevel`,`number`,`address`,`password`) 
                  VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$dateOfBirth','$gender','$fitnessLevel','$number','$address','$password')" or die(mysqli_error()));
```

I can echo any of the variables and they show, so the data from the form is being passed to here.

Thanks :-)

Comment: default password is blank by default, did you change it?

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal , yes I have changes password to root, removed and and got new error. "Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: @mitkosoft No errors, the formSubmitted.php page is opening successfully.

Comment: `mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(`firstName`,`lastName`,`dateOfBirth`,`gender`,`fitnessLevel`,`number`,`address`,`password`) 
                  VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$dateOfBirth','$gender','$fitnessLevel','$number','$address','$password')") or die(mysqli_error($db));`  you put die() inside `mysqli_query` which is not correct

Comment: Please `prepare` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) your statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you putted `die(mysqli_error())` inside `mysqli_query()` which is not correct, do like below:-

```
 mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(`firstName`,`lastName`,`dateOfBirth`,`gender`,`fitnessLevel`,`number`,`address`,`password`) 
            VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$dateOfBirth','$gender','$fitnessLevel','$number','$address','$password')") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Note:- add `$db` in `mysqli_error()` so that if any error occur you will come to know.